# Why does the combination of Laravel Gate and Policy return NULL when logging in to a message?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, policy, laravel-gate

In the Laravel 10 application, I use authorization of actions using `Gate`, `Policy` and `Spatie`. The authorization of the event itself works fine, that is, where it is necessary and who it is necessary to let and does not let, respectively.

However, there was a small problem with the following case: the user is not an admin, has no privileges in any way, respectively, the `before` method returns `false` to check the administrator role. Next, a check should be run in the `canEditStatus` method, from where a response with a code and an error message should be returned, since, again, the user does not have privileges. Instead of the message and the code, `NULL` is returned, although the check really failed.

Below are the sources with the policy, controller, and response in Postman.

##### `app\Policies\UserPolicy.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    private const ACCESS_ALLOW_MESSAGE = 'Ok';

    private const ACCESS_DENIED_MESSAGE = 'Access denied';

    public function before(User $user): bool
    {
        return $user->hasRole('admin'); // <-- it doesn't pass, that's right
    }

    public function canEditStatus(User $user): Response
    {
        if ($user->hasPermissionTo('edit status')) {
            return $this->allow(self::ACCESS_ALLOW_MESSAGE, 200);
        } else {
            return $this->deny(self::ACCESS_DENIED_MESSAGE, 403); // <-- expect this answer
        }
    }
}
```

##### `app\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\Api\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\RecordsNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $updateRequest, string $id): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($updateRequest->has('is_active')) {
            $authorize = Gate::inspect('can-edit-status', User::class);
            if ($authorize->denied()) {
                dd($authorize); // <-- authorization result dump
                abort($authorize->code(), $authorize->message());
            }
        }

        // next is the update logic
    }
}
```

And, in fact, the response to the request from Postman:

[image: Response to the request from Postman]

Comment: Can you confirm that you are actually hitting `canEditStatus`? It seems that you are hitting an undefined ability, this returning plain false.

Comment: @EduardoPacheco, thanks for the tip, I started checking it and sell that one of the Spatie permissions was not created, because of this, the method did not work correctly. Now it works correctly, returning the code and message only if i delete the `before` method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comment, it is possible this is not hitting the actual code.
enter code here
In my experience, laravel policies should be referenced exactly like the method definition and accessed through the user:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Requests\Api\UserUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\RecordsNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class UserController extends ApiController
{
    public function update(UserUpdateRequest $updateRequest, string $id): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($updateRequest->has('is_active')) {
            if ($updateRequest->user()->cannot('canEditStatus')) {
                dd($authorize); // <-- authorization result dump
                abort($authorize->code(), $authorize->message());
            }
        }

        // next is the update logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Yes, this option will work, but in this case I will not be able to get the code and error message that can be passed to the user, I have only a boolean value on my hands...

Comment: Should the policy or gate really be responsible for that though?

Comment: There is such an example in the documentation, why not?